# Cannot Render Mirror Hallway

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I am trying to render this image using Cycles. This is how it looks in my viewport, compared to how it is after making the image. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Screenshot settings:

[image]

Comment: the speckles are noise, often referred to as fireflies due to various settings in your materials and in the render settings for cycles.  I assume the missing skeleton bits are because of an object obscuring the skeleton in the render but not in the viewport. (Look for objects that have the camera enabled but the 'eye' for viewport disabled.  If you post screenshots of your materials and render settings it might be possible to help.  It also might be possible to use a denoiser to reduce the fireflies.

Comment: @MartyFouts I have denoising turned on. I also don't have any obejcts obscuring the skeleton. I've hit alt + h to reveal anything that might be hidden and there's no reason for anything strange to appear. Added some screenshots to my question

Comment: can yo share a blend file? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Answer (score 1):

Render is set to 1 sample?

Change that to at least 32 to match the viewports samples.